# Can AngularJS listen for $locationChangeSuccess on refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am listening for $`locationChangeSuccess` in Angular using this code:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
  console.log('Check, 1, 2!');
});
```

However, it will only log in the console that the location has changed when I navigate to a new link. Naturally, this makes sense. My question is, **how can I make Angular listen for** `$locationChangeSuccess` **in the event that I refresh the page?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't register from within a controller because $locationChangeSuccess occurs before the route is matched and the controller invoked. By the time you register, the event has already been fired.

However, you can subscribe to the event on $rootScope during the application bootstrap phase:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        console.log('$locationChangeSuccess changed!', new Date());
    });
});
```

Comment: Any idea what kind of argument returns?

Comment: Is there a way I can get the state parameters passed in the URL, inside the function of `$locationChangeSuccess`. `$stateParams` returns empty when I print that out

Answer (score 6):

You probably want a listener on `window.onbeforeunload` which is called just before the window  unloads it's resources (refresh).

Comment: Great answer. I think I'll go with Sly's, just because it looks to be the Angular way. Again, though, I totally appreciate the help!

Comment: I doubt this works, because the page is not refreshed when URL's are handled by Angular. Angular "replaces" the content of the current page. There is no reload, so no window.onbeforeunload IMHO