# $locationChangeSuccess not firing on browser back action in IE10 and IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

On a project I'm working on, a number of checkboxes in a view are used to apply and remove a set of filters from a search result set. The values of these checkboxes are written to the query string to facilitate the ability to pre-load a filter state via navigation. To simplify, I'll pretend there is only one checkbox and ignore the fact that there's supposed to be some filtering.

To ensure the state in the query string is correct, when a check-box is checked, a function is called which writes the checkbox's value to the query string. The checkbox's value is bound to a scope property called "checkBoxValue".

```html
<input ng-model="checkBoxValue" 
       ng-change="WriteValueToQueryString()"
       type="checkbox"/>
```

In addition to this, when there is an update to the query string, I call a function which gets the current value from the query string and writes it to $scope.checkBoxValue. It ensures that the value in my controller and the value in the query string are in sync with one another, regardless of where a change in value originates. The altogether simplified version of this all looks like this:

```coffeescript
app = angular.module 'myApp', []

app.controller 'MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', ($scope, $location) ->

    $scope.GetValueFromQueryString = () ->
        queryStringValue = $location.search()['checkbox'] or false
        #making sure I write a true/false and not "true"/"false"
        $scope.checkBoxValue = queryStringValue is true or queryStringValue is 'true'

    $scope.WriteValueToQueryString = () ->
        $location.search 'checkbox', $scope.checkBoxValue.toString()

    $scope.$on '$locationChangeSuccess', () ->
        $scope.GetValueFromQueryString()
]
```

When I check the box, it changes checkBoxValue, updates the value in the query string, and everything is just lovely. If I press the "Back" button in my browser, it notices that the location has changed, updates its value to match the query string (efectively undoing my last), and everything is just lovely.

...Unless I'm using Internet Explorer 10 or 11...

In IE10 and IE11, the browser "Back" action doesn't **appear** to do anything. In reality, it **is** performing a browser "Back" action (when I look at it, the query string reads as it should after a browser "Back" action). The problem seems to be that $locationChangeSuccess never fires. The value is thus never retrieved from the query string, which means that my checkbox's actual value is never updated from the query string. Eventually, if you press "Back" enough, it just boots you off to whatever actual page you were on before you got to my own page, checkbox still in the state it was before you started hitting "Back".

Funny thing is? IE8 and IE9 have no problems with this.

**Link to CodePen (try it in IE10 or IE11)**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaGwt/

Thanks for reading my ramblings for this long. Any help you could give on this issue would be tremendously appreciated!

**Things I've tried:**

```
$scope.$watch ( () -> $location.search() ), () ->
    $scope.GetValueFromQueryString()
```

Which appears to behave identically to what's listed above. No dice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can AngularJS listen for $locationChangeSuccess on refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200239/can-angularjs-listen-for-locationchangesuccess-on-refresh)