# AngularJs Location.path does not get current path without page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am building a loan application with it.  What I am trying to do is setup a way for users to go to the next and previous pages of the application.  What I have setup works if I refresh the page, otherwise it will not pull the current path.  Here is what I have.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    /*Controller for navigation*/
    app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $http, $routeParams) {

        var str = $location.path();
        $scope.currentPage = str.replace("/", "");

        /*Get nav.json with navigation data*/
        $http.get('/configs/nav.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.step = data; 
        });

        /*Set active status for nav buttons*/
        $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
            var active = (viewLocation === $location.path());
        return active;
        }

    });
```

Template

```
<div class="forms">
    <div class="wrapper">

       <div ng-view></div>

        <div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="steps in step" ng-show="steps.url=='{{currentPage}}'">
                <div ng-show="'{{step[$index+1].url}}'!=''" class="next">
                    <a href="#/{{step[$index+1].url}}">Next &#10097;</a>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="'{{step[$index-1].url}}'!=''" class="previous">
                    <a href="#/{{step[$index-1].url}}">&#10096; Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Json

```
[
{"number": "1",
 "title": "Loan Information",
 "url": "loan"
},
{"number": "2",
 "title": "Personal Information",
 "url": "personal"
},
{"number": "3",
 "title": "Income Information",
 "url": "income"
},
{"number": "4",
 "title": "Debt Information",
 "url": "debt"
},
{"number": "5",
 "title": "Reference",
 "url": "reference"
},
{"number": "6",
 "title": "Document & Submit",
 "url": "submit"
}
]
```

You can ignore the isActive in the controller that is for the top navigation.

Edit:Also tried the solution found here [Can AngularJS listen for $locationChangeSuccess on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200239/can-angularjs-listen-for-locationchangesuccess-on-refresh)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
            $rootScope.currentPage = $location.path().substr(1);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where else would I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's because your `NavCtrl` is only being created once, thus your code setting `$scope.currentPage` only runs once.

You can listen to the [`$locationChangeSuccess`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeSuccess) event in your controller to detect changes to the current path

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.currentPage = $location.path().substr(1);
});
```

Comment: That seems to replicate the issue.  I put it inside the controller is that right?

Comment: Hmm that is what I did.

Comment: Tried a runblock as well with no success. See update.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue is there any other suggestions you would have?

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill other than change your template logic to `ng-show="steps.url == currentPage"`, no

Comment: Hmm didn't work.  I'm going to see if I can fiddle the whole thing.

Comment: Actually no need your suggestion to change the template logic worked.  Any idea on why {{currentPage}} didn't work?

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill I think you were comparing `steps.url` to the literal string `"{{currentPage}}"`. `ng-show` / `ng-if` don't do interpolation IIRC